# Is there a Hausdorff space with a $\sigma$-locally finite basis but no $\sigma$-discrete basis?

Tags: gn.general-topology, hausdorff-spaces

In short, the question is in the title: *is there a Hausdorff space with a $\sigma$-locally finite basis but no $\sigma$-discrete basis?*

---

**A bit of context:**

Given a topological space $X$, a family $\mathcal{U}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ is locally finite (resp., discrete) if for every $x\in X$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ that intersects only finitely many (resp., at most one) elements of $\mathcal{U}$.

We say $\mathcal{U}$ is $\sigma$-locally finite (resp., $\sigma$-discrete) if it can be partitioned into countably many locally finite (resp., discrete) families.

Nagata-Smirnov-Bing metrization theorem states that the following are equivalent:

1. $X$ is metrizable,
2. $X$ is $T_3$ and has a $\sigma$-locally finite basis,
3. $X$ is $T_3$ and has a $\sigma$-discrete basis.

In particular, the two properties (having a $\sigma$-locally finite basis, and having a $\sigma$-discrete basis) are **equivalent for $T_3$ spaces**.

On the other hand, there are examples of ($T_0$) spaces having a $\sigma$-locally finite basis but no $\sigma$-discrete basis, e.g. the poset $([\omega_1]^{<\omega}, \supseteq)$ with the [Alexandrov topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology).

So the two properties are **not equivalent in general**.

I tried searching but I could not find any Hausdorff counterexample.

**My question is:** are the two properties still equivalent for $T_2$ spaces?

---

**Note:**

Say that $\mathcal{U}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ is star-finite if every $U\in\mathcal{U}$ intersects only finitely many elements of $\mathcal{U}$.

We say $\mathcal{U}$ is $\sigma$-star-finite if it can be partitioned into countably many star-finite families.

Since every star-finite family is also $\sigma$-discrete, we get the following

**Remark:** $\sigma$-discrete $\iff$ $\sigma$-star-finite $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma$-locally finite.

In particular, if a space has a $\sigma$-locally finite basis but not a $\sigma$-discrete basis, the locally finite families should be very far from star-finite.

Comment: Does this help at all? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060083/proof-that-a-t-1-space-has-a-locally-finite-basis-iff-it-is-discrete

Comment: This one also might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440635/locally-finite-open-cover-and-sigma-discreteness

Comment: Lastly, here are all the spaces in $\pi$-base that are Hausdorff, have a $\sigma$-locally finite basis, and are not $T_3$. But, I can't seem to filter the search on $\sigma$-discrete basis. If you know some equivalent characterizations of that notion, maybe the answer is in $\pi$-base. https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%24%5Csigma%24-Locally+Finite+Base+%2B+%24T_2%24+%2B+%7E%24T_3%24

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know that $\pi$-base had also a filter for spaces with a $\sigma$-locally finite basis!
Unfortunately though, it seems that it does not contain any example of a space that has a $\sigma$-locally finite basis and is $T_2$ bu not $T_3$, nor second countable (you want to avoid second countable spaces as they are always $\sigma$-discrete). https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%24%5Csigma%24-Locally+Finite+Base+%2B+%24T_2%24+%2B+%7E%24T_3%24+%2B+%7ESecond+Countable

Comment: The first math.stackexchange link does not seem very related.
The second one instead seems related (that is basically the idea for the $T_0$ counterexample I wrote in the question) but I could not exploit that idea to obtain a Hausdorf space.

Comment: Every example in the pi-Base of a space with $\sigma$-locally finite base was deduced automatically from it being second countable or pseudometrizable https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000054/spaces it'd be great to add an example or theorem to satisfy Cla's search.

Comment: I think $T_3$ in your post can be generalized to regular (where both bases are equivalent to pseudometrizable).

Comment: Following your last remark, its maybe worth pointing out that every star-countable open covering is $\sigma$-discrete.